# Slow response from CosmosDB in another region using Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am in UK and I need to get data from a CosmosDB in Australia.
The container size is not a problem. It's only 3 records. The point is: It's very clear that the issue is latency not just involving distance, but involving gateways between 2 azure regions.

By researching I found something that can help me: Direct Connection instead gateway.
But the examples that I found cannot explain how to specify the protocol to use TCP instead HTTPS

```
        CosmosClientOptions cco = new CosmosClientOptions()
        {
            SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions()
            {
                PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
            },
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct
        };
CosmosClient c = new CosmosClient(
                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"CosmosDb_{thisEnv}_{reg}_url"),
                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"CosmosDb_{thisEnv}_{reg}_ClientSecret"),
                    cco);
```

I am using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos, but I found examples on this page https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/194 that's looks like a different library and I see:

```
ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
    ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp
};

this.documentDbClient = new DocumentClient(
    new Uri(documentDbEndpointUrl),
    documentDbAuthKey,
    connectionPolicy
);
```

First question: When I set ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct, is this setting my protocol automatically to TCP ? I could not noticed any performance improvement on it. So, I am not sure.

Yes, I really need to access data in a different region and I am aware that Microsoft recommends to not do it.

Comment: Are you using V2 or V3 SDK? and regarding different regions, you are right recommendation is to collocate application and database together in same region

Comment: Azure.Cosmos 3.24

Comment: Do you see slowness just in the first request or always?

Comment: First, @GauravMantri, but since it's on Azure App Functions...every call on any endpoint will behave like the 1st connection. A handshake on the gateway will be required.

Comment: Not necessarily true. Please see this link - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/manage-connections.md#c-1

Comment: Thanks, @GauravMantri ! But I can't find any information about how to implement this in an Azure Functions project. It's starts with a "#R" that I am not familiar...it does not say what kind of file, class, etc I need to create, then ask to create a new .proj file without mention details...Yeah. it looks like the solution, but very poorly documented.

Comment: I think I will open a new thread to ask about how to implement this ! thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Few things to unpack in the question and in comments.

Latency between both UK regions to either Australia region averages about 250ms. Any measurement of latency needs to discount for this in all cases. Please note that these are averages measured over a 30-day period. It is not uncommon to see spikes with much greater latencies. This needs to be accounted for if any part of what you are building is latency sensitive with transient error handling (i.e. retries) in your code. For more information on latencies in Azure's WAN see, [Azure network round-trip latency statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/networking/azure-network-latency)

You are using the .NET v3 SDK. Direct mode is set by default. You do not need to do anything. That said, it will only have a slight to possibly no impact on the latency between these two regions.

First request to the Cosmos DB service will always include greater latencies due to handshakes and other initialization that occurs when making a new connection to the service. Subsequent requests do not incur this latency.

It is important to understand the trade-offs between using consumption-based Azure Functions vs. those on App Plan (Premium). The former can incur unexpected latencies due to instance recycling.

Implementation is simple and depends on what you're trying to do. If you're just building a rest API over your database then an http function will work. There are also built in triggers and bindings for Cosmos DB as well. This sample here from the [Cosmic Works GitHub repo](https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/CosmicWorks/blob/master/change-feed-categories/Program.cs) shows how to implement change feed processor to respond to changes in a container. But same code works for how to initialize Cosmos resources for any type of Azure Function.